# What factors determine consumer group rebalancing time?

Tags: apache-kafka

We recently saw some issues in production where a consumer group was taking on the order of minutes to rebalance when a consumer left the group.

This particular consumer group has about 8-10 consumer members at any given time and is subscribing to roughly 15 topics, each with 32 partitions.

Essentially trying to figure out what we should look to do in order to make rebalancing take less time. (e.g. do we try and reduce the number of consumers per group? less partitions per topic? etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so after significant trial and error found that the biggest factor in rebalancing time was the number of total topics & partitions that a given consumer group was trying to subscribe to.

We had a consumer group that was basically covering about 600~ partitions across 20 or so topics. By changing up our polling strategy, etc. we were able to move to a consumer group per topic and times have dropped drastically.

Answer (score 2):

As of Kafka0.10.1, there are two configs that affects the rebalance: `session.timeout.ms` and `max.poll.interval.ms`.

Setting `session.timeout.ms` to a relatively low value enables the coordinator to detect the failures more quickly and trigger a rebalance on a timely basis.

Setting `max.poll.interval.ms` to a relatively low value means the rebalance will usually complete fast but the risk of commit failures will increase which is a tradeoff.

Comment: gotcha, so the fact that we had max.poll.interval.ms set to a high value is probably what was causing the rebalances to take so long? is there any good reference for what is a good ratio for the two settings or just figure out something that works best for you?

Comment: You have to figure out how long you want the rebalance to take and then set `max.poll.interval.ms` to that value to see if everything works fine. If this triggers more rebalances, also try to lower `max.poll.records`